# Find the string from a long URL using Regular Expression in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to extract the string from the long URL, for example I have a URL like `grazie/gifts.html?mkt_tok=eyjpijoiwvrrne9estnprgmyttjabcisinqioijhu0d`
I only want this part `grazie/gifts.html`. However, I also have a a URL like this 
`/grazie/new-member-bonus.html` and I want the whole thing, which means I want the string starting from `/grazie` and end as `html`.

I have tried to use the regular expression: `^/grazie+.html$`, but it always return `/grazie.html`. I remember that '.' represents any character. I am kinda stuck.

Comment: Try `^grazie.*\.html`. If lazy quantifier is working, `^grazie.*?\.html` will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` represents any character, but only once. Thus, you would need to use `\.*`, since the `*` represents a wildcard of any number of the previous character (for example, `'s*'` would match `''`, `'s'`, `'ssssss'`, and so on. You should try using `'grazie.*\.html'` On a side note, the `+` wildcard matches at least one of a character before it, so your RegEx expression would have matched `'/grazie.html'`, `'/graziee.html'`, `'/grazieeeeee.html'`, and so on.